# How to bind collection of Grid

Tags: wpf, binding

I have WrapPanel and  Grid's tamplate. Grids should be inside of WrapPanel. How to make collection of Grids and bind them? (Also i use Caliburn Micro Package) [(Grids inside of WrapPanel)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYTwY.png)

Comment: you need to use an `ItemsControl` with a `WrapPanel` as its `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

Comment: And you should read [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview)